# How does shift function work in the following code?

Tags: javascript

I know how map function works and how I should use the map function. But while playing with the monkey code, I could not understand how shift function works here?

```js
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(a);
a.map(function(){
  a.shift();
});
console.log(a); // [4,5,6]
```

I am totally confused how `a` is now [4,5,6] ?

Comment: [MDN documentation on shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: I did that but it didn't help me..

Comment: changing the size of the array while you iterate over it is a bad idea, just for future reference, it isn't a hard no, as some problems require you to do so, it's a pause for thought to make sure it's necessary

Comment: It may be illuminating if you add a parameter to your function and log it, like so: `function(el){ console.log(b); a.shift(); }`. The result with your example is `0, 2, 4, 6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is `[4,5,6]`, it's just because the array size is reduced and the map function doesn't run 7 times in this case. Let me explain with an ascii diagram:

```
map contains        expected run times      after shifted       actual run times
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]     7                       [1,2,3,4,5,6]       1
[1,2,3,4,5,6]       6                       [2,3,4,5,6]         2
[2,3,4,5,6]         5                       [3,4,5,6]           3
[3,4,5,6]           4                       [4,5,6]             4
```

Now, map function expected run times is actual run times. Thus, no need to run map function again.

Hope, this clears up things behind the scene.

Answer (score 3):

> I am totally confused how a is now [4,5,6] ?

You are iterating an array while taking away items from it. Eventually you will run out of items to remove no more iterations are happening.

Just put a `console` statement in the code

```js
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
a.map(function(v, i){
  console.log(a)
  console.log( a.shift() );
});
console.log(a); // [4,5,6]
```

You can observe that it goes through 4 iterations of removing an item from the front.

> (7) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] //first iteration without any shift
>
> 0 //first item removed
>
> (6) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  //resulting arr after first iteration
>
> 1
>
> (5) [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>
> 2
>
> (4) [3, 4, 5, 6]
>
> 3
>
> (3) [4, 5, 6] //**resulting array after 4th shift (since no more iterations are possible now as number of items in array are less than 4**

Answer (score -1):

well the length of the array is being .shift() for each iteration of .map() so you are shortening your array while mapping, so a[0] becomes 1 for the first iteration while the total length of the array becomes 6.

Then you shift() on index[1] which now is 2, then index[2] which now is 4, then index[3] which now is 6, so that 6 is put into index[2].

Then the rest of the array is empty and a is [4,5,6] :)